# M1 flutter cannot build Ios - Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both

Tags: flutter, build, cocoapods, apple-m1

I tried almost everything, but every time I try to build I get this error.[image]

Comment: did you manage to solve this? im having the same problem